# Wrong result after hasing string with SHA-256

Tags: java, android, string, character-encoding, sha256

I am trying to hash a string using `SHA-256` but the result is wrong and contains special characters.

Code:

```
String password = "test";
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] sha256Result = md.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String result = new String(sha256Result, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Result string:

```
��Ё�L}e�/��Z���O+�,�]l��
```

Comment: The returned array is the raw bytes of the hash, if you want it in hex you should check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java).

Comment: Please replace `hasing` by `hashing` in your headline to make it easier to find your article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashing procceed correctly, but the result is consisted of array of bytes. To make it readable, use the `StringBuffer`. As example of conversion, take a look on the [example on Mkyong's webpage](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/).

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < sha256Result.length; i++) {
    sb.append(Integer.toString((sha256Result[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you hash it is ok. If you want it as a hex string after:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.HexBinaryAdapter;
String hex = (new HexBinaryAdapter()).marshal(md.digest(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```